# Do I Need to use ref With make_pair to Return a Reference?

Tags: c++, reference, visual-studio-2017, c++14, std-pair

Given an object like this one:

```
struct Foo {
    string _mem;
    pair<bool, const string&> Func() { return make_pair(true, _mem); }
};
```

Am I actually returning a reference to `_mem` or not? My understanding was that in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) [`make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) would forward my type allowing the return I'm using to capture it as a reference to the object's `_mem`.

This behavior seems consistent with what I'm seeing in gcc 8: http://ideone.com/adz17e But when I try to run this on [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) it seg-faults. If I change to return `make_pair(true, ref(_mem))` it works, but I didn't think that I needed to. Which one of these behaviors is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I actually returning a reference to `_mem` or not?

No, you are not. `make_pair(true, _mem)` is a `std::pair<bool, std::string>` that is a copy of that your member. It's then converted to a `std::pair<bool, std::string const&>` in the return type which means you're returning a reference to a temporary which is immediately destroyed. Unconditional dangling.

Recall that C++ is a value semantics language. Nothing is a reference by default, you have to be explicit about this.

You have two ways of doing this. You can either mark that you want a reference:

```
return std::make_pair(true, std::ref(_mem));
```

`make_pair` will unwrap `std::reference_wrapper`s, so this expression is a `std::pair<bool, std::string&>`.

Or, you can just be explicit:

```
return std::pair<bool, std::string const&>(true, _mem);
```

Which you can write shorter as:

```
return {true, _mem};
```

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined behaviour.

Since c++11 make_pair is defined as:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

In your case `_mem` is Lvalue, so `T2` is deduced to be `string&`, but `V2` of result pair is deduced from `std::decay(string&)`. `std::decay` always discards reference. Returned pair has dangling reference in `second` member.

Comment: I edited the question to add my workaround, but I'm not certain that it makes sense with your answer. I'm now returning: `make_pair(true, ref(_mem))` and that seems to work. Wouldn't that also decay to just returning by type?

Comment: @JonathanMee `decay` on `reference_wrapper<string>` gives you `string&`. You don't need to use `ref`, just put explicitly types in template arguments list:   `pair<bool,const string&>(true,_mem)`. This `make_tuple(true,_mem)` is the same as `pair<bool,string>(true,_mem)` so `_mem` is copied inside local scope that is why you get dangling reference.